# pandas read sql query improvement

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

So I downloaded some data from a database which conveniently has a sequential ID column. I saved the max ID for each table I am querying to a small text file which I read into memory (max_ids dataframe).

I was trying to create a query where I would say give me all of the data where the Idcol > max_id for that table. I was getting errors that Series are mutable so I could not use them in a parameter. The code below ended up working but it was literally just a guess and check process. I turned it into an int and then a string which basically extracted the actual value from the dataframe.

Is this the correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do before I replicate this for about 32 different tables? I want to always be able to grab only the latest data from these tables which I am then doing stuff to in pandas and eventually consolidating and exporting to another database.

```
df= pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE Idcol > %s;', engine, params={'max_id', str(int(max_ids['table_max']))})
```

Can I also make the table name more dynamic as well? I need to go through a list of tables. The database is MS SQL and I am using pymssql and sqlalchemy.

Here is an example of where I ran max_ids['table_max']:

```
Out[11]:
0    1900564174
Name: max_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your `max_ids` DF? or just post an output of `print(max_ids.head())`

Comment: sure, I made an edit

Comment: your `max_ids` - doesn't look like a pandas data frame?!? can you post an output of `print(max_ids.head())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your `max_ids` DF looks as following:

```
In [24]: max_ids
Out[24]:
   table  table_max
0  tab_a      33333
1  tab_b     555555
2  tab_c   66666666
```

you can do it this way:

```
qry = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE Idcol > :max_id'

for i, r in max_ids.iterrows():
    print('Executing: [%s], max_id: %s' %(qry.format(r['table']), r['table_max']))
    pd.read_sql_query(qry.format(r['table']), engine, params={'max_id': r['table_max']})
```